# WindowsBase dll not supporting in ASP.net Core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, openxml

Am Using DocumentFormat.OpenXML to convert file to dataTable as i know to resolve "The Type Package is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" Issue .

i have added Windowsbase dll also from path C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\WindowsBase.dll

Even though i am getting same problem in ASP.NET Core 2.0 Project.

Please tell me that it will work in ASP.NET Core 2.0 or any other libraries to include?

Comment: dotNet Core is designed to be a cross platform framework so it probably doesn't include anything platform specific. If you're running your service on a Windows server then just use the latest standard dotNet framework version (4.7.2 I think).

Comment: We planned to use this in AWS and Unix also that why we preferred ASP.Net Core 2.0 .

Comment: Glancing through the docs, it looks like WindowsBase.dll gives access to certain operating system functions (scheduling jobs for threads, package access, etc). If that is the case, then it wouldn't make sense for it to be available for a non-Windows environment, since other operating systems are just different.